# How to make a zoom control on a Android App that has an image?

Tags: android

I am making an Android App that has an image on the Layout.

Does any one know how i can make it where the user can zoom in on the picture with the zoom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zoom Control only is for the Map View (bind-handler), not for ImageView (no bind-handler).
There is a couple of "how to zoom an ImageView" q&a avail at Stack Overflow.